# Login with Google using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-signin

I don't know how to handle the reason in the ExternalLoginCallback part. Can someone help me?
Đoạn code bên dưới là tôi tham khảo. Hãy giúp tôi sửa nó

[image]

Here ExternalLogin:

[image]

I don't know how to handle the reason in the ExternalLoginCallback part. Can someone help me?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code not an image of your code